# How can I count something before inserting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// cookies
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
|   id    |         email           |     cookie       | date_time  |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
| int(11) |      varchar(50)        |   varchar(128)   |  int(11)   |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
| 1       | jack_2009@gmail.com     | ojer0f934mf2...  | 1467204523 |
| 2       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | ko4398f43043...  | 1467205521 |
| 3       | matrix_john23@gmail.com | 34fjkg3j438t...  | 1467205601 |
| 4       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | 0243hfd348i4...  | 1467206039 |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO cookies VALUES(NULL, $email, $hash, unix_timestamp())
```

Now I need to check following **condition** before inserting:

The number of rows *(for specific user)* should be less than:

- `5` per hour
- `10` per day
- `50` per month
- `100` per total

---

I just can check the last case:

```
INSERT INTO cookies(id, email, cookie, date_time)
SELECT NULL, $email, $hash, unix_timestamp()
FROM cookie
WHERE email = $email AND
      100  >=  ( SELECT count(1) FROM cookies WHERE email = $email )
```

Well, how can I add other conditions?

Comment: does `id` correspond to a unique user?

Comment: you can use stored procedure and within that you can handle this

Comment: @vkp `id` column is PK *(so it is unique)*. but `email` column isn't unique.

Comment: You need either a stored procedure or a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok I'm familiar with triggers, but how it can help me?

Comment: which "hour", which "day", etc... ?

Comment: @Uueerdo What? I meant was if there is more than `5` rows in a day, that inserting should fail.

Comment: @stack if you want i can provide required format of  stored procedure

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Well thank you .. I will be glad to see it.

Comment: Any day? If there were 6 rows in a day that happened 2 months ago, the insert should be cancelled? (Edit: Ok, i see comment above.)

Comment: @Uueerdo You know, I want something like this: when you want to ask a new question on stackoverflow, it just lets you to ask `6` questions per day, `50` question per month and etc .. how it checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive on whether the `>`'s (in the group by) should be `>=`'s, but I think this will do what you are asking.

```
INSERT INTO cookies(id, email, cookie, date_time)
SELECT NULL, $email, $hash, unix_timestamp()
FROM cookie
WHERE email = $email 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS rowsInLastHour
           , COUNT(CASE WHEN date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS rowsInLastDay
           , COUNT(CASE WHEN date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
                        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS rowsInLastMonth
           , COUNT(1) AS rowsEver
        FROM cookie
        WHERE email = $email
        HAVING rowsInLastHour > 5 
          OR rowsInLastDay > 10 
          OR rowsInLastMonth > 50 
          OR rowsEver > 100
    )
;
```

- It counts all the rows (for the email) that had date_time values in the last hour|day|month by using `now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR|DAY|MONTH` to find when the last hour|day|month started, and counting those values that occurred after those starting times.
- It then uses the `HAVING` to only yield the singular result (aggregation such as `COUNT` that does not have an associated `GROUP BY` clause always results in 1 row), if any of the limits you specified were exceeded.
- Then the `NOT EXISTS` returns true if there were no results (because the limits were not exceeded).

*Edit: Updated comparisons to use unit timestamps, as needed by question.*

Comment: Ok, this query checks just the **last** ones or **any** ones ?

Comment: The last ones, I'll add detail/explanation in an edit.

Comment: As you see in the question, The value of unix_time column is an integer number of seconds. But `now() - INTERVAL ...` returns a date-time format. So do you think this would work? `date_time > now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`

Comment: Oh, I nearly overlooked that; you should be able to do `date_time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`, and similarly for the DAY and MONTH versions.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Just may you please tell me, can I use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: @stack `NOT IN` would be a different query. You would have to select only the email, but still filter on all the same aggregate calculations with a having clause. Also, while I doubt it helps in this case (due to the aggregate calculations used), it is my understanding queries in `NOT EXISTS` clauses do not always have to exactly fully execute (and seem more appropriate to me when using correlated subqueries such as these).

Answer (score 1):

You can use stored procedure and within that you can handle this. Pass your insert values to this stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(id int, email varchar(45), cookie varchar(45), date_time datetime)
BEGIN
DECLARE countval INT;

SET countval = (SELECT sum(1) FROM cookies WHERE email = $email );

IF (countval is null) THEN
 // do something
ELSEIF (countval>10) THEN
  // do something like that
ELSE 
// do something
END IF;

 // insert query

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you can call it usin " call sp_test(1,"sasa","wew",3232); "