# How can I control my website's inputs when they are entered by users?

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, security

I have a question and answer website like SO. I have some limitations on some of facilities. For example an user cannot vote who has less than 20 reputation. Or an user cannot close a question until earning at least 200 reputation.

Ok well, there is also somethings which don't have any limitation, like writing an answer for questions. In this case, **a bad user** can write multiple irrelevant answers for multiple questions and makes my database huge with useless information.

So I guess I need to check something before inserting a new answer, Am I right? Or anyway, how can I manage my website's inputs? As I mentioned, in my current algorithm, a bad user *(like a spammer or hacker)* can simply enter lots of useless data in my database, and then maybe I understand it after 1 day *(which is too late)* which in this case, it takes some times to block him and remove all his data.

In conclusion, I like to know, *(for example)*, how a website like SO handle that? Do I need a separated query before inserting a new answer for checking? Or what?

**Note:** I use PHP *(for server-side codes)* and MySQL *(for database codes)*.

Comment: Yes, you need a query for checking. SO uses many queries to decide what users are allowed to do.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107025/how-can-i-count-something-before-inserting#38107363

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's pretty easy. You should store the last operation time and compare it with now.

```
function insertSth(//your args){
    $minimumInsertInterval = 10; // Minimum 10 seconds.
    //You should check if interval ended.
    if( ( microtime() - $_SESSION['lastInsertTime'] ) <= $minimumInsertInterval ){
        //User can't do any operation.
        return false;
    }
    //Insert operations
    //At the end of your insert operations you need to write this microtime to Session.
    $_SESSION['lastInsertTime'] = microtime();
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be a approach .. thank you .. upvote

Answer (score 0):

You need to take measures like Erol described, but you need logical checks as well. Create an `actions` table which describe possible actions and create a `privileges` table which will describe rules. Then create a table between the two where you will store what privileges are needed for each action. Before you execute an action check that all the privileges needed to it are fulfilled.